# How can i install .deb files from terminal , i tried different ways in askubuntu

Tags: software-installation, deb, error-handling, teamviewer

i am trying to install teamviewer and i am getting the following error and the entire process is as follows

```
kittu@kittu-355V4C-356V4C-3445VC-3545VC:~$ sudo dpkg -i teamviewer_linux_x64.debdpkg: error processing archive teamviewer_linux_x64.deb (--install):
 cannot access archive: No such file or directory
Errors were encountered while processing:
 teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
```

the file is in home/downloads/teamviewer_linux_x64.deb

Comment: It says "No such file or directory" because you're missing the right path to the file. You should do ~/Downloads/teamviewer.deb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to execute the command in the wrong directory. You have two ways to correct it and get going:

1. **Using the GUI:**

   - Open files(the file browser in ubuntu) and go to your `Downloads` directory(this should be visible when you open the file browser) and then double click on the team viewer .deb file.
   - This will open the software center and take some time to load everything and then you should see the install button on the top right hand side.
   - Click on "Install" and this will install team viewer for you.
2. **Using the command-line:**

   - Open a terminal (press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and type gnome terminal and open the application) and then type the following one line at a time:

     ```
     cd ~/Downloads
     sudo dpkg -i  teamviewer_linux_x64.deb
     ```

and then enter your password when prompted and press <kbd>Return</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Some packages come as standalone but require other dependencies which may be third party libraries so you need to fix that yourself. You can just do it the same way and resolve dependencies like this

```
 sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb && sudo apt-get -f install
```

This will not only install the package but also try to resolve it's dependacies. Helps me alot. or like he said, [GUI](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/natty/gdebi/) does work as well

**Good luck !**