# installing debian package with dpkg

Tags: dpkg, debian

I am learning the dpkg's usage. So, I am trying to install the wps-office package as example.

```
sudo dpkg -i wps-office_10.1.05672~a21.deb
```

which returns an error: `Can not access the archive: No such file or folder`
What's wrong did I do?

Comment: A classic one, you are forgetting the path to the file. Simply type `sudo dpkg -i ` then drag the file on to the terminal window. Should be a dupe of a few others.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“cannot access archive: No such file or directory” when installing a package using dpkg](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231667/cannot-access-archive-no-such-file-or-directory-when-installing-a-package-usi) or [How can i install .deb files from terminal , i tried different ways in askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477111/how-can-i-install-deb-files-from-terminal-i-tried-different-ways-in-askubuntu) -- see also [How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must specify the absolute or relative path to the file. If you are running it from a terminal, and you are located in the file path, just run:

`sudo dpkg -i ./wps-office_10.1.05672~a21.deb` Note the `./`

Otherwise, you could use:

`sudo dpkg -i <path_to_file>/wps-office_10.1.05672~a21.deb` where `<path_to_file>` could be something like `/home/$USER/Documents`

or

`sudo dpkg -i ../../wps-office_10.1.05672~a21.deb` if you are in a subfolder down two levels of the file folder.